# How to write scalable SVG without ViewBox parameter?

Tags: c#, css, wpf, xaml, svg

I am using a C# library which doesn't support the `viewBox` parameter in SVG files, but without it I get my images cut-off as they can't scale properly, details below ...

I am programming a mobile application, using the xamarin forms platform and [this](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG) nuget plugin (in XAML and C#). The plugin has a very limited SVG support, so I have had to manually change the svg files. When generated, the Google+ image has the following first tag, however, when I use this file, I get the following error message:

```
<svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>Google_Round</title><
```

> System.Exception: Invalid parameters to context creation
>     at CoreGraphics.CGContext.set_Handle (IntPtr value) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/src/CoreGraphics/CGContext.cs:161
>     at CoreGraphics.CGContext..ctor (IntPtr handle, Boolean owns) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/src/CoreGraphics/CGContext.cs:141
>     at CoreGraphics.CGBitmapContext..ctor (IntPtr data, nint width, nint height, nint bitsPerComponent, nint bytesPerRow, CoreGraphics.CGColorSpace colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo bitmapInfo) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/src/CoreGraphics/CGBitmapContext.cs:62
>     at NGraphics.iOS.Custom.ApplePlatform.CreateImageCanvas (Size size, Double scale, Boolean transparency) [0x0005c] in :0
>     at SVG.Forms.Plugin.iOS.SvgImageRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1 e) [0x0010f] in :0

If I Change that first tag, to a copy of the first tag from a known workign example, I have the following SVG File.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" height="300" width="300" version="1.1" fill-opacity="0"> xml:space="preserve">
        <path fill="#54534A" d="M2204.344,4414.691v-122.67h81.643h81.642l-1.237,6.804c-0.619,3.505-1.649,10.515-2.474,15.462l-1.443,8.659
            h-61.438h-61.644v38.141v38.141h54.635h54.635v16.493v16.494h-54.635h-54.635v36.079v36.08h60.613h60.407l1.443,10.515
            c0.825,5.979,2.062,13.401,2.68,16.493l1.237,5.979h-80.818h-80.612V4414.691z"/>
    <!-- Various Strokes omitted -->
    </g>
    </svg>
```

This gives me the following display of what would otherwise be a full G+ icon. I assume it is because I have lost the `viewBox` info from the file. How else can I include this information to ensure my svg scales appropriately, without causing the plugin to fail?
 [image: Icon Comparison]

Comment: I suspect that the problem you are having with the first file is because it doesn't have a `width` or `height` specified. What happens if you add `width="512" height="512"` to the `<svg>` tag in that file.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thank you very much - that's fixed it! if you post an answer, I'll mar it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem you are having with the first file is because it doesn't have a `width` or `height` specified. What happens if you add

```
 width="512" height="512"
```

to the `<svg>` tag in that file. Does that make a difference?